# Why this code removes first 3 char?

Tags: c

I'm learning C and I find this program but I couldn't understand why it removes first three char. What's the math behind this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(void){
    int *ptr;
    char *str="hello world";
    char *s_ptr;
    ptr = (int *)str;
    ptr++;
    s_ptr = (char *) ptr;
    printf("%s", --s_ptr);
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: they're pointers, you can print out their values as integers, and if you put in the output before/after each of your statements, you'll see what each line is doing and be able to figure out WHY this is happening.

Comment: In C, `++ptr` means "add 1 to ptr", which means "make ptr point to the next *thing*, whatever kind of thing it points to". At that point in the program, `ptr` points to `int`s, so adding 1 makes it point to the next `int`, which is 4 bytes away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof(int)` on your platform seems to be 4 bytes. When you do `ptr++` the pointer is incremented by 4 bytes, not by 1 byte as you expect since the type of pointer `ptr` is `int` not `char`.

Comment: That's what I exactly expected, 1 byte!
Thank you.

Comment: I also figured out if I define ptr with double it will point next 8 byte. Learned from you. Danke schön.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to understand the how not the why. A char spans 8 bits, also known as a byte. An integer spans 4 bytes on a 32 machine. In C, you can do arithmetic on pointers. When you write `ptr++`, the address to which `ptr` points is incremented by as many bytes as the type it points to has. In your case it is incremented by 4 bytes. The next line converts `s_ptr` to `char*` (`s_ptr` pointing to the `o` in `hello world`). The next line subtracts 1 so now it points to the `l` before the `o`. `printf` does the rest.. So remember: you can do arithmetic on pointers and it depends on the size.

Comment: So will,

 `int *ptr;
 char *str = {0,1,1,0,0,1,0};
 ptr = (int *)str;
 printf("%d\n", *ptr);`

this code works with same idea?
0,1,1,0 will be printed.

Comment: This code takes the first 4 bytes to which str points and interprets the bit pattern as an integer and prints it; so this code prints a number. You are using integers for characters there so 0 and 1 are ascii code for some characters. Why don't you try running this?